# Removing most recently added node from Scalax Graph

Tags: scala, graph, collections

I have a `graph` with each `node` being a `hashmap` with `key:value` being `String:String`. I want to delete the most recently added `node` from the `graph` and  **update**  the same `graph`. I seem to be having an issue with it. I am able to filter out the most recently added `node` using the following code:

```
g1.nodes.filterNot(x=> x == g1.nodes(g1.nodes.size-1))
```

where g1 is the graph defined as,

```
var g1: Graph[FeatureStructGraph, DiHyperEdge]
```

and `FeatureStructGraph` is a `case class` defined as follows:

```
case class FeatureStructGraph(hashMap: mutable.HashMap[String,String])
```

I'm unable to figure out how to update `g1` to just have the nodes without the most recent one. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: did you try `var g1 = g1 - g1.nodes.filterNot(x => x == g1.nodes(g1.nodes.size-1))`

Comment: @Hamuel do you mean `g1 = g1.nodes.filterNot(x => x == g1.nodes(g1.nodes.size-1))`? This has a `type mismatch` error `Expression of type Set[Graph[ContextManager.this.FeatureStructGraph, GraphEdge.DiHyperEdge]#NodeT]doesn't conform to expected type Graph[ContextManager.this.FeatureStructGraph,GraphEdge.DiHyperEdge]`